# aggregation_execution_exception : Invalid aggregation order path,Sub-path points to non single-bucket aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

**when i run es aggration :**

```
"aggregations": {
    "author": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author",
        "size": 100, 
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": {
          "interactions-c>interactions-sum": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "interactions-c": {
          "children": {
            "type": "interactions"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "interactions-sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "interactions.likes"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**exception:**

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "aggregation_execution_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid aggregation order path [interactions-c>interactions-sum]. Buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end. Sub-path [interactions-c] points to non single-bucket aggregation"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "article_20200910",
        "node" : "fLYvCQjfTEKG0QIivtn3Hg",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "aggregation_execution_exception",
          "reason" : "Invalid aggregation order path [interactions-c>interactions-sum]. Buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end. Sub-path [interactions-c] points to non single-bucket aggregation"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

**this is my index mapping:**

```
{
  "article" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "author" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "interactions" : {
          "properties" : {
            "comments" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "dislikes" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "forwards" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "likes" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "views" : {
              "type" : "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "joinField" : {
          "type" : "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals" : false,
          "relations" : {
            "article" : [
              "interactions"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i create a index which use join field (parent :article ;children :interations )
what i want:

1. aggreate interations number by author (author is a parent index field,interations is a children field)
2. then order by interations sum value desc

but es says childern aggs is not a single bucket aggs!So is there any way to this?